# how to use css clip-path with svg path to mask html element

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to use SVG to make a water drop with an animated wave. I use SVG `clipPath` to define the clip path and CSS `clip-path` to mask the inner div, and I need the water drop in the center of the page.
http://jsfiddle.net/sigmadfzb/gbdj0k0q/

When I move the outer div (absolutely position) to the left or the top, the water drop will not display in the page (See http://jsfiddle.net/sigmadfzb/uz4mkzww/4/). I want the water drop in the center position. If I remove the `ab` class and its CSS property, the water drop will show.

I confuse that the clip-path just can be used in left-top of the page? Is some positioning wrong in my page?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the width='0' and height='0', leaving just

```
    <svg>
```

In the  attributes, change 'uri(waterMask)' to

```
    'url(#waterMask)'
```

This works in Firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/98tjgbw6/1/

Comment: thanks, but it's not working in chrome. chrome not support? it can be

Answer (score 0):

You can add `margin: 0 auto` to `.water-box` to center it horizontally and use JavaScript to position it vertically when the page loads and on window resize.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/gbdj0k0q/3/)

```
var main = document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0];

function position() {
    main.style.transform = 'translateY(' + ((window.innerHeight / 2) - 40) + 'px)';
}

position();
window.onresize = position;
```

```js
var main = document.getElementsByClassName('main')[0];

function position() {
  main.style.transform = 'translateY(' + ((window.innerHeight / 2) - 40) + 'px)';
  main.style.webkitTransform = 'translateY(' + ((window.innerHeight / 2) - 40) + 'px)';
}

position();
window.onresize = position;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: coral;
}
.main {
  position: relative;
}
.water-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#waterMask);
  clip-path: url(#waterMask);
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.water-inner {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-image: url(http://121.42.52.51/wave.svg);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  -webkit-animation: wave_water 1s infinite linear;
  animation: wave_water 1s infinite linear;
}
keyframes wave_water {
  from {
    background-position: left top;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 160px top;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes wave_water {
  from {
    background-position: left top;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 160px top;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="ab">
    <div class='water-box'>
      <div class="water-inner"></div>
    </div>
    <svg width="0px" height="0px">
      <defs>
        <clipPath id='waterMask'>
          <path fill="#008CA4" d="M25,0C25,22.911,0,31.225,0,56.387C0,69.419,11.194,80,25,80c13.799,0,25-10.581,25-23.613
  C50,32.448,30.113,22.911,25,0z" />
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <rect x='0' y='0' width='30' height='40' clip-path='uri(waterMask)' />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this css for centering element.

```
.water-box{
margin: 50% auto;}
```

If you want exact centering you should add `display: table;` to `.main`  and `display: table-cell; vertical-align:middle;` to `.water-box`